# Define CSS style using XML / XSL parser

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have a XSL/XML parser to produce html code.

The xml is like this.

```
<root>
  <a>
   <url> http://image.jpg </url>
   <x> 100 </x>
   <y> 200 </y>
   ...
  </a>
</root>
```

and the XST should be something like this. In style I want do define a background url using the value of xml node. How can I do it?

```
<xsl:template match="root">
   <xsl:for-each select="a">
    <div class="crop_image" style="background:url("<xsl:value-of select="url"/>") -<xsl:value-of select="x"/>px -<xsl:value-of select="y"/>px">"</div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are "Attribute Value Templates", which allow you to write values from your XML directly into attributes

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="a">
    <div class="crop_image" style="background:url({url}) -{x}px -{y}px">"</div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally, so `{url}` for example will be replaced with `http://image.jpg` in your output.